# CSharpCodeProvider Setting Compiled Details

Tags: c#, .net, file

Not sure if I am asking this about the correct process for what I want the final outcome to be.

I am fiddling around CodeCompiler and generating EXE's inside the test app I have set up. So the compile works and I can create a hello world and all, I've linked some ReferencedAssemblies as well just to fiddle with it and so what the process is like compiling code inside a compiled program.

Anyway, so when I compile the executable the file details aren't what I want it to say AKA no details at all(Description, Version, Copyright). What is the process/options I should look into for setting the file details either during/precompile in the code itself or a process after compile and file creation then assign the data to the file?

Basically just want to assign the file details that I have in strings to the file itself pre or post-compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after working with a dev friend and totally forgetting about the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the project. I was able to set the compiled program details using the same idea but in the head of the code source after the using statements, so basically this is my solution/way to set the details:

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Test Compile Proj")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Compiler Test")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Then after that is the namespace, etc...
Sorry to answer my question right away but hopefully this helps anyone else that was beating their head against the table during late night coding sessions.